# Query all that matches a certain criteria

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a log with thousands of different events and messages types to run a query to find and replace some certain data like here is one example
event 1

```
 "eventID": "Ar39084",
      "data2": "http://sfa.stanly.local:8787/nices-uri/msa/PRAS-             TAM80/root/BLA_Notification::LINKDOWN-ISA_NA-Ar39084~2F538
      "data3": "[excm][132.19][78.65][68493435][Ar39084]"
      "data4": "AGV.SDA.Ar39084"
```

event 2

```
  "eventID": "Ar39079",
  "data2": "http://sfa.stanly.local:8787/nices-uri/msa/PRAS-TAM80/root/BLA_Notification::LINKDOWN-ISA_NA-Ar39079~2F538
  "data3": "[excm][132.19][78.65][68493435][Ar39079]"
  "data4": "AGV.SDA.Ar39079"
```

So what I want is to search all that applies to group 1 in my notepad++ search here is the query I have,

```
  "eventID": "(.*?)",
```

So I want all that matches the eventID (Ar39084 and Ar39079) group 1 content so this will match data2 , data 3 , data 4 and so on and this query can match as well event 2 , event 3 and so on..

So that I can be able to replace in the log Ar39084 Ar39079 Ar394354 anywhere and any other string that matches the query

So after apply the replacement my log can look like this:

Event 1

```
 "eventID": "${variable}",
      "data2": "http://sfa.stanly.local:8787/nices-uri/msa/PRAS-             TAM80/root/BLA_Notification::LINKDOWN-ISA_NA-${variable}~2F538
      "data3": "[excm][132.19][78.65][68493435][${variable}]"
      "data4": "AGV.SDA.${variable}"
```

Event 2

```
  "eventID": "${variable}",
  "data2": "http://sfa.stanly.local:8787/nices-uri/msa/PRAS-TAM80/root/BLA_Notification::LINKDOWN-ISA_NA-${variable}~2F538
  "data3": "[excm][132.19][78.65][68493435][${variable}]"
  "data4": "AGV.SDA.${variable}"
```

Comment: anyone ? I expend 3 days looking the internet for a solution

Comment: I'm afraid this can't be done with Notepad++. You have to write a script in your favorite scripting language. For example a perl one-liner like: `perl -ape '$id=$1 if (/"eventID": "([^"]+)/); s/$id/\${variable}/g;' inputfile > outputfile` does the job.

Comment: Does the structure of data2, data3, data4 is always the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help:

I did a grouping on `(Ar\d+)` to match `Ar` followed by `\d+` for any number of digits.

[image]

**UPDATE**:

Based on the potential for other events starting with something other than simply `Ar`, the find regex grouping changes to:

```
([a-zA-Z]{2}\d{5,})  // 2 characters followed by 5 (or more) digits.
```

That will match events named:
Jm37908
Za94025
Sw02834
Pt012345678  (should there ever be more than 5 digits)
Plus others with similar formats

You can try the [regex here](https://regex101.com/r/7innwS/1/).

Comment: Thanks Paul , Well that is a really useful one and a good approach and it may help me with some other stuff, but the structure of this event ID is randomly generated and it can change all over the different events, and as in the log I have pretty different ones I need another trick, some examples here :

  "eventID": "Jm37908",
  "eventID": "Za94025",
  "eventID": "Sw02834",

Comment: @TaysVanDuurenFernández: I wondered about that, I used the example in the question as the basis. See the update appended to my answer. That should cover the other examples that you mentioned, as well as many others. Plus the one extra added to simply show that it can cover more than 5 digits.

Comment: Great! ... when you get a chance, please consider [acceptance](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

Find what: `"eventID":\s*"\K(\w+)("[\s\S]*?)(?=\b\1\b)|\G(\w++)(?=(?:[^"](?!\3))*"\s+(?:"eventID"|\z))|\G(\w++)([\s\S]*?)(?=\b\4\b)`

Replace: `\${variable}\2\5`

You have a demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/HHS0sL/3/).

It should work with any identifier that consist of letters, numbers and underscores as long as there's some word boundary around then (which seems to be your case)